# What does the X in JAX-RS Stand For?

Tags: java, jax-rs, terminology

In the acronym JAX-RS, what does the X stand for?

I know that RS Stands for Restful Service and J is Java and A for [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). What then what about the X?

Comment: Seriously? I put your question into Google and scanned the results page and got the answer...

Comment: Nothing. It was just carried over from JAX-WS and the other javax*

Comment: @John3136 I googled the same question, and the accepted answer is now displayed at the top as a card.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off-topic. JAX-RS is a programming specification, not software and certainly not a general computing software. Its naming conventions are on-topic here. Moreover, this question was [asked again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490684/what-does-jax-literally-mean-in-java-ee-programming).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
JAX-RS  = Java API for RESTful Web Services
```

The `X` remained as part of the nomenclature. e.g.:

```
JAXR    = Java API for XML Registries
JAXP    = Java API for XML Processing
JAXB    = Java Architecture for XML Binding
JAX-RPC = Java API for XML-based RPC
JAX-WS  = Java API for XML Web Services
```

So, the letter `X` is for `XML`.

Comment: If 'x' is the same as in "javax", x would be fore eXtension, which makes more sense since u can expose RESTful services using no XML.

Comment: I believe that it comes from x as extension, java extension for restfull web services

Answer (score 7):

It was just carried over from JAX-WS and the other javax.ws.rs
so it can be said that the x comes from java(x) of the java package.